# Issue with Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, cell, datagridviewrow

[image]

Please help me to solve this error as I tried in more than one way
When I try to change in cell number 5, the error appears, but the error does not appear if I try to change in any other cell

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For item As Integer = 0 To Employee_Shift_DetailDataGridView.RowCount - 1
           
            Employee_Shift_DetailDataGridView.Rows(item).Cells(5).Value = "001"
            
        Next
    End Sub
```

Thanks.

I tried to change the selection mode

Comment: Obviously there are not six columns in your grid then.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Nothing to do with SQL Server

Comment: You are databinding, why not just change the appropriate object in the datasource `bs`?